# Masking only specific words with Huggingface

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

What would be the best strategy to **mask only specific words** during the LM training?

My aim is to dynamically mask *at batch-time* only words of interest which I have previously collected in a list.

I have already had a look at the `mask_tokens()` function into the `DataCollatorForLanguageModeling class`, which is the function actually masking the tokens during each batch, but I cannot find any efficient and smart way to mask only specific words and their corresponding IDs.

I tried one *naive* approach consisting of matching all the IDs of each batch with a list of word's IDs to mask. However, a for-loop approach has a negative on the performance.

.

---

*Side issue about word prefixed space - Already fixed*

Thanks to @amdex1 and @cronoik for helping with a side issue.
This problem arose since the tokenizer, not only splits a single word in multiple tokens, but it also adds special characters if the word does not occur at the begging of a sentence.
E.g.:

> The word "Valkyria":
>
> - at the *beginning* of a sentences gets split as ['V', 'alky', 'ria'] with corresponding IDs: [846, 44068, 6374].
> - while in the *middle* of a sentence as ['ĠV', 'alky', 'ria'] with corresponding IDs: [468, 44068, 6374],

It is solved by setting `add_prefix_space=True` in the tokenizer.

Comment: Try putting a space before your sentence, this will solve the issue of words having different representations.

Comment: @amdex I've tried but did not have the expected impact. I'm using the WikiText-2 raw and several sentences already begging with spaces because of the format.

For example, this is what I've got before adding the additional space at the beginning: ['Ġ', 'Ċ', 'Ġ=', 'ĠV', 'alky', 'ria', 'ĠChronicles'], this is after: ['Ġ', 'Ġ', 'Ċ', 'Ġ=', 'ĠV', 'alky', 'ria', 'ĠChronicles'].

Comment: Right, but I mean when Valkyria occurs at the beginning of a sentence. You will no longer get 'V', but get 'ĠV' instead, this making the occurrences of Valkyria identical, regardless of whether they occur at the beginning or in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: You mean to add a space before everything (both the sentences both the words in my list), so that they will have a unique representation.
This might work, but it seems a "dirty" workaround. I'm worried other similar tricks of the tokenizer might get unspotted and break the comparison.

Comment: You can apply `add_prefix_space=True` to the tokenizer to get the desired beheaviour described by @amdex

Comment: Why don't you simply create your own method which masks only your specified words? The class you have mentioned does a lot more as you want. Sure you can modify it, but how much do you want to keep of the existing functionalty? As far as I can tell nothing, therefore you should simply create your own method which can even run before the tokenizer.

Comment: @cronoik If I modify the dataset when it gets read, the words of interest would be permanently masked. Instead, I need to mask them dynamically at batch-time (following some stochastic approach), which is why I've mentioned the mask_tokens() function.
I've made the original post more explicit on this point.

Comment: Still you can simply write your own class which produces the batches and masks with an stochastic approach of your choice.

Comment: @cronoik this is exactly the point: how to make this efficiently? Or as stated in the original question "What would be the best strategy?".
I can, of course, going with a for-loop through all the IDs on each batch and check whether they match my list of IDs. But this would be extremely slow and would not exploit any built-in functionalities of the Huggingface library. 
I was wondering whether there are more efficient approach using or a different strategy or making the aforementioned approach more efficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217648/discussion-between-cronoik-and-gabrer).